# How to get variation specific image from a listing with eBay API GetItem

Tags: vb.net, ebay-api

I'm trying to get variation images, I have tried multiple things and nothing seems to work out.

I have one variation on all my listings called size. Within this I have Small, Medium, Large, Set of 3.

I have managed to get the main image with this code:

```
Dim fetchedItem As ItemType
Dim Apicall As GetItemCall = New GetItemCall(Context)
Apicall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll)
fetchedItem = Apicall.GetItem(myItemID)
Dim imageURL As String = fetchedItem.PictureDetails.GalleryURL.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different API call: GetSingleItem. You can either POST or GET your API request. http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html

Be sure to use an IncludeSelector for additional data in the response.